# Is it possible to have a linear function that is bounded within $(-1, 1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

More explicitly, is it possible to have a function $f(x)$ that satisfies:

$$
f(x) \in (-1,1) \text{ for } x \in \mathbb{R}
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = m \text{ for } x \in \mathbb{R} \text{, where $m$ is a real constant }
$$

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1
$$

$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = -1
$$

$$
f(0) = 0
$$

and if this function cannot exist, is there a proof for it not existing?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = m $ together with $f(0)= 0$ implies $f(x) =mx$ for all $x$.

Comment: Did you try to sketch a linear function with the desired properties?

Answer (score 3):

If $f'(x) = m$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$ then it's not possible, as that implies $f(x) = mx+c$ and is in contradiction that $f(x)\in(-1,1)$.

If you make the condition a bit weaker, for example $f'(x) = m$ almost everywhere, then it is possible. For example
$$ f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} x-\ln n+ 1 & \text{for }x\in[\ln (n-1),\ln n), \quad n\in\mathbb N, n\ge 2, \qquad x\neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{for }x=0\\ x+\ln n-1 & \text{for }x\in(-\ln n, -\ln (n-1)], \quad n\in\mathbb N, n\ge 2, \qquad x\neq 0  \end{array} \right. $$
Has $$ f'(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \text{for }x \neq 0,\pm\ln n, \quad n\in\mathbb N\\ \text{does not exist} & \text{for }x = \pm\ln n, \quad n\in\mathbb N \text{ or }x=0\end{array} \right.$$
and 
$$ \forall x\in\mathbb R:-1 < f(x) < 1$$
$$ f(0)=0 $$
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = 1$$
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} f(x) = -1$$

Answer (score -1):

I realised that since $f(x) = mx$, and $m = \frac{1}{n}$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{n} = 1$ implies that there is a number $n$ such that $\frac{\infty}{n} = 1$, which is impossible (since $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is undefined.) So it doesn't exist.